# Does an answer need to have code to be considered complete?

Tags: discussion, answers

I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25043457/1593651) to a question, and got a comment from a user saying I didn't actually answer the question.

Should I put actual code in my answers to have them be considered complete, or is it okay the other way? I'm not really sure, since the how-to-ask guidelines ask for code, most answers include code, but I believe a question can be possibly answered in a complete manner without necessarily including code.

What are your thoughts on the issue and how should I make my answers 'complete'?

**Though I thank those who read this meta question and liked the answer I linked to, please do not go and upvote that answer. That was not the point of this post.**

Comment: Your answer is fine either way. Answers don’t always need code; it’s just useful to have, some (most, maybe) of the time.

Comment: I find answers with code most helpful when I read other people's questions and answers to solve my problem, because it helps me make sense of everything they wrote. Try describing a car to someone that has never seen one. It is very hard until you actually show them a picture of it. Pretty much all answers benefit from the tiniest bit of code you mix in.

Comment: It's tempting to post `return False` as an answer to this question.

Comment: of course you **do not need** to include code.  nice answer by you.  it's completely normal on this site these days, unfortunately, that people add silly, pointless comments on good answers.

Comment: I would throw an exception

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It depends on how complete you want your answer to be, and how much reputation you'd like to receive.

Answers with code generally outscore answers without code.

They're also more useful for future visitors.

Comment: For the answer I posted, it's a simple one liner which OP wanted to know how to modify to work properly. I'd think copy-pasting the line from the question to the answer would be redundant.

Comment: It depends on the question. However, I have a tendency to put in sample code, then go back and edit my answer later, if I have an even better answer. Even my one-liner answers may get more detail later once I have compiled a sample that I can confirm works.

Comment: Really? It's mainly about reputation? Surprised to read this from a moderator O_o

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be saying that the OP doesn't want to have to actually *think*.  I know that's true for some, but that doesn't seem to me to be the audience we should be seeking.  (And I'm still wondering what the point of reputation points is, after 5000 or so. Until we can use them at Starbucks or trade them in for frequent flier miles, they seem, uh, "pointless".)

Answer (score 40):

In my opinion, neither a question nor an answer requires code to be complete.  It's just that code is often (but not always) the most effective way to communicate.

In a limited number of cases a written description of a problem or solution is better.  The important thing is for the question to contain ALL the needed information (easily 50% of "it crashed" questions with code don't include complete error messages and exception stacks, eg).

And for answers it's far more important to explain WHY the problem occurred than it is to say "Use this code" with little or no explanation.

(Though, when you do explain something, there is unfortunately the more than occasional Opie who keep badgering you to write his code for him.)

Comment: To quote Linus, "Words are cheap, show me your code"

Comment: Opie. O-pie. Oh-pie. Oh, pie. Wut?

Comment: @bjb568 - OP - Original Poster.  But I think is has a "ring" to that makes it suit an OP who is acting immature.

Comment: @bjb568 Opie. Opee. O.P. OP. Original Poster.

Comment: ("Opie" is a child's nickname (short for what I don't know) that was, at one time, not uncommon in the rural US.  It's best known as the name of Opie Taylor, son of Andy Taylor in the old "Andy Griffith Show" on US TV.  (And the role of Andy Taylor was played by Ron Howard, a fairly well-known TV actor and producer.)  The name conveys a sense of childish innocence.)

Comment: @Humdinger - I'm thinking it was Lucy that said that.

Comment: @HotLicks Lucy? Who's Lucy? But it was definitely Linus, Except I got the quote wrong, the correct quote is "*Talk* is cheap, show me *the* code"

Comment: @Humdinger http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peanuts

Comment: @HotLicks Ah, I see. I would like to see the strip when she says that, or anything similar

Comment: @Humdinger Lucy was known for her (rather obnoxious) pronouncements -- never said precisely that, I'm sure (the strip was firmly anchored in the 50s), but likely said something that would be a good substitute.

Comment: +1 specifically for *"And for answers it's far more important to explain WHY the problem occurred than it is to say "Use this code" with little or no explanation."*  I would much rather see explanation and no code than to see code with no explanation.  I myself have given many code-free answers, usually when the question is asking about a big-picture idea and an outline of an algorithm is all that is needed.  Occasionally, that has led to comment streams from someone who really has no clue how to implement the algorithm, but most times a push in the right direction is all someone needs.

Comment: (Oops, I meant to say that the role of *Opie* Taylor was played by Ron Howard.)

Answer (score -1):

Different kinds of questions need code and don't need code.

In particular, a question that provides code and asks about an error in it, should probably be provided with code (even if it's just an errant keyword) as an answer.

Questions that might be better answered more broadly, or with a concept rather than an implementation - "How do you most efficiently search for a change in a value", "Use a binary tree algorithm" is a fine answer and doesn't need code (both because binary tree algorithms are something programmers should be familiar with, and because it would make the answer unnecessarily long).

Answer (score -1):

Not always in my opinion:

- For general problems that are likely to help future visitors a relevant sample of code is usually an important part of an answer.
- But for tutorial/homework questions I tend to upvote only answers that provide guidance without explicitly giving a cheap answer.

For example I like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25093618/2642204) mainly because the poster didn't provide an exact solution. The accepted one is also fine, although it contains a bit too much of a solution for my taste (I also upvoted it though).