# Was this question not actually Too-Broad?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, needs-more-focus

I recently flagged [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687650/how-to-communicate-over-local-network-between-c-sharp-desktop-application-and-mo) as too broad. From my understanding the user has not tried to implement anything, they are asking for a way (or many ways) to do it and is essentially "Give me the codez". However my flag was declined.

So did I flag incorrectly?

Comment: I would agree...too broad and have close-voted as such.

Comment: @Paulie_D Okay just wanted to make sure I hadn't mis-understood how the flag was meant to be used... on a side note does that mean my flag will stay declined?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes....but that happens occasionally.

Comment: @Paulie_D Okay thanks for the help

Comment: @RandomLogic no the flag was declined

Comment: It's **give me teh codez** :D

Comment: I would say, you can probably take this over to SE's Programmers and update it a bit to fall in their guidelines. That's a great place to go when you're still at the designing stage and not yet code-deep, or at least not yet at a PoC on the horizon.

Comment: @prudhvi Ahhh so close

Comment: It's broad, yet it has an accepted answer with a positive score (as of this writing). Doesn't that make it a successful transaction for the people who do care about the question?

Comment: @user3071284 IMO even if it has helped people, if it is off topic, too broad etc... for whatever reason it should be closed as such. I'm not saying downvote it to oblivion or delete it because it has helped people, but close it to show future visitors it is not a good question fit for the site.

Comment: This is a helpful explanation of why to close: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason/215220#215220

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The question went into the Close Votes review queue and, [for some reason, several users felt it should be left open](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/10936755). They were wrong. That question is, as you said, extremely broad. But because enough people voted to leave it open, your flag was declined automatically by the system.

So, to clarify, your flag was valid. It's just that the moderators never saw it because the Close Votes review queue handled it (incorrectly).

Comment: Four years ago, when the question was originally asked, it might have been more palatable, and since it has a good answer that apparently addresses the question, the close reviewers must have decided it was OK.  In general, my feeling is that coherent questions this old that managed to be productive don't merit special attention; we have bigger fish to fry.

Comment: @RobertHarvey You're probably right about why the reviewers voted the way they did. And I wholeheartedly agree that we don't generally want to focus too much on old, once-productive questions like this one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: On the other hand, leaving such questions lying around lead to "but this question was not closed" whining :/

Comment: @RobertHarvey The only reason I flagged the question is that I saw it when searching for help. I don't go around looking to close questions.

Comment: too broad states "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format."  Since he is asking something like "how can I communicate from my Android app with my C# app" there are only going to be a few (1, maybe 2) answers, and the answers do not necessarily need to be long, so why is this question too broad?

Comment: It would be great to have the highly up-voted and useful answers that don't follow the rules, migrated to a place where people could find the information they want.  There are many questions that don't follow the rules, but have huge amounts of up-votes and views.  If you delete all those posts, it's traffic that stackoverflow will loose.  Stackoverflow probably wants as much traffic as possible.  An incredible amount of views are generated by lots of posts that don't follow the rules.  Quite a conundrum isn't it?  If the rules were well enforced, stackoverflow would not be as popular.

Comment: @Trisped The problem is that to answer that question, one has to do one of two things: (1) stay at a ridiculously high level, like "write an API," or (2) write an incredible amount of detail, such as code for *how* to get the apps talking. The question itself is extremely open-ended (`is it possible to... create some kind of web service...? How should I do this, which technology to use? Or are there alternative ways to achieve something like this?`). One could argue that it's a request for recommendations, which would make it off-topic. But really, it's just too broad to start with.

Comment: @SandyGood Questions that are highly up-voted and useful don't tend to get closed in the first place; they don't ever *get* highly up-voted if they're completely off-topic. And this is not a situation in which that's a problem. The post in question had a -5 score.

Comment: Yes, the question you listed is to broad, but the actual question (adjusting for the general ignorance of the user) is quite simply answered with, "Yes, use `HttpListener` class built into .NET."  [Code is not required](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267256/641833), especially with a high level "Can I" request.  That said, a better answer would have a code sample and more details.